# Keeping Track of Word Proximity

Tags: r, text-mining

I am working on a small project which involves a dictionary based text searching within a collection of documents. My dictionary has positive signal words (a.k.a good words) but in the document collection just finding a word does not guarantee a positive result as there may be negative words for example (not, not significant) that may be in the proximity of these positive words. I want to construct a matrix such that it contains the document number,positive word and its proximity to negative words.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do that. My project is at a very very early stage so I am giving a basic example of my text.

```
No significant drug interactions have been reported in studies of candesartan cilexetil given with other drugs such as glyburide, nifedipine, digoxin, warfarin, hydrochlorothiazide.
```

This is my example document in which **candesartan cilexetil, glyburide, nifedipine, digoxin, warfarin, hydrochlorothiazide** are my positive words and no significant is my negative word. I want to do a proximity (word based) mapping between my positive and nevative words.

Can anyone give some helpful pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I would suggest not to use R for this task. R is great for many things, but text manipulation is not one of those. Python could be a good alternative.

That said, if I were to implement this in R, I would probably do something like (very very rough):

```
# You will probably read these from an external file or a database
goodWords <- c("candesartan cilexetil", "glyburide", "nifedipine", "digoxin", "blabla", "warfarin", "hydrochlorothiazide")
badWords <- c("no significant", "other drugs")

mytext <- "no significant drug interactions have been reported in studies of candesartan cilexetil given with other drugs such as glyburide, nifedipine, digoxin, warfarin, hydrochlorothiazide."
mytext <- tolower(mytext) # Let's make life a little bit easier...

goodPos <- NULL
badPos <- NULL

# First we find the good words
for (w in goodWords)
    {
    pos <- regexpr(w, mytext)
    if (pos != -1)
        {
        cat(paste(w, "found at position", pos, "\n"))
        }
    else    
        {
        pos <- NA
        cat(paste(w, "not found\n"))
        }

    goodPos <- c(goodPos, pos)
    }

# And then the bad words
for (w in badWords)
    {
    pos <- regexpr(w, mytext)
    if (pos != -1)
        {
        cat(paste(w, "found at position", pos, "\n"))
        }
    else    
        {
        pos <- NA
        cat(paste(w, "not found\n"))
        }

    badPos <- c(badPos, pos)
    }

# Note that we use -badPos so that when can calculate the distance with rowSums
comb <- expand.grid(goodPos, -badPos)
wordcomb <- expand.grid(goodWords, badWords)
dst <- cbind(wordcomb, abs(rowSums(comb)))

mn <- which.min(dst[,3])
cat(paste("The closest good-bad word pair is: ", dst[mn, 1],"-", dst[mn, 2],"\n"))
```

Comment: I almost got what I was looking for. Thanks nico!

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at either one of the

- [Natural Language Processing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) Task View on CRAN, or
- text-mining package [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tm) on CRAN ?

Comment: Nice packages, didn't know them! Still, I don't think R is the best tool to do this kind of analysis.

Comment: Yes, I use the tm package very frequently!