# inspect specific document from DocumentTermMatrix for specific terms

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I used tm package from R for text mining. This is what my code looks like:

```
library(tm)
```

Load the data in R

```
pathToData = "R/group_data"
 newsCorpus = Corpus(DirSource(pathToData, recursive = TRUE), 
                readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
```

Length of news corpus

```
      length(newsCorpus)
```

Pre-processsing the corpus data

```
newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus,removePunctuation)
newsCorpus[["103806"]]

newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus,removeNumbers)
newsCorpus[["103806"]]

newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
newsCorpus[["103806"]]

newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
newsCorpus[["103806"]]

newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus, stripWhitespace)
newsCorpus[["103806"]]
```

Corpus elements to plain text

```
newsCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(newsCorpus))
```

Document Term matrix with TFIDF weights

```
docTermMatrix = DocumentTermMatrix(newsCorpus, 
                               control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf, 
                                              minWordLength = 1,
                                              minDocFreq = 1))
```

Dimensions of resulting matrix

```
dim(docTermMatrix)
```

The docTermMatrix looks like this:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1986, terms: 22213)>>
 Non-/sparse entries: 173995/43941023
 Sparsity           : 100%
 Maximal term length: 163
 Weighting          : term frequency - inverse document frequency (normalized) (tf-idf)
```

Now I want to inspect the docTermMatrix for the document "101287" and look for the terms "textmining", "clustering". But since the document term matrix has changed the document names(rows) to 1,2,3,4... , I can no longer find the document named "101287" and look for the columns "textmining", "clustering". Is there a way I can preserve the document name ?
Apologies if I am missing on something..

## Output from R for the above code

```
> library(tm)
  > pathToData = "R/group_data"
  > newsCorpus = Corpus(DirSource(pathToData, recursive = TRUE), 
              readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))

 > length(newsCorpus)
    [1] 1986

 > newsCorpus[["103806"]]
  <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
  From: cheekeen@tartarus.uwa.edu.au (Desmond Chan)
  Subject: Re: Honda clutch chatter
  Organization: The University of Western Australia
  Lines: 8
  NNTP-Posting-Host: tartarus.uwa.edu.au
  X-Newsreader: NN version 6.4.19 #1

  I also experience this kinda problem in my 89 BMW 318. During cold
  start ups, the clutch seems to be sticky and everytime i drive out, for
  about 5km, the clutch seems to stick onto somewhere that if i depress
  the clutch, the whole chassis moves along. But after preheating, it
  becomes smooth again. I think that your suggestion of being some
  humudity is right but there should be some remedy. I also found out that
  my clutch is already thin but still alright for a couple grand more!

 > newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus,removePunctuation)
 > newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus,removeNumbers) 
 > newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
 > newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
 > newsCorpus = tm_map(newsCorpus, stripWhitespace)

 > newsCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(newsCorpus)) 

 > docTermMatrix = DocumentTermMatrix(newsCorpus, control = list(weighting =     weightTfIdf,minWordLength = 1,minDocFreq = 1))  
                                                                                              
                                              
 > dim(docTermMatrix)
 [1]  1986 22213



>inspect(docTermMatrix["1","bmw"])
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 0/1
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 3
Weighting          : term frequency - inverse document frequency (normalized) (tf-idf)

    Terms
Docs bmw
  1   0

>inspect(docTermMatrix["103806", "bmw"])
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(docTermMatrix, "103806", "bmw") : 
Subscript out of bounds.
```

Comment: The document term matrix is now a matrix. Did you try `inspect(dtm["101287","textmining"])` to look at the values? You need to use proper row/column indexing.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that and it gives me this error:                        Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(docTermMatrix, "101287", "textmining") : 
  Subscript out of bounds.                                                    I can only run this command on docTermMatrix now :                             inspect(docTermMatrix[1,1:10]) and it gives me this kind of result :                 
Docs aaa aaaaa aaaah aaareadmetxt aafreenetcarletonca
   1   0     0     0            0                   0

Comment: Well, I was unable to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) your problem based on your description. It worked for me (tm_0.6).

Comment: So if I am understanding it correctly are you able to do inspect(dtm["101287", "textmining"]) and get some result. Well I understand the data might be different. But you are able to access dtm using this notation ?

Comment: Okay so "101287" was the name of my document in the corpus. When it was converted to a DocumentTermMatrix , the size of documentTermMatrix dim(dtm) = 1986 22213. So it has 1986 rows and 22213 cols. Now when i search for document name "101287" it will not exist. So I am trying to figure out how can I access the document with name "101287" and I don't know at which row it is present in DocumentTermMatrix.Name of the document is the only information I have.

Comment: The indexes are independent from the names so that shouldn't matter. You should focus on making your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can run the exact same code as you to see why it might not be working for you.

Comment: I have added my R output . I hope this might help in catching some mistake that I am repeatedly making. I have two inspect methods and the second one still gives me the same error.

Comment: BTW , I figured out one thing from the code : If I do not convert the corpus to plain text using this : newsCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(newsCorpus)). I can access the document from the matrix using document name("103806"). But if I convert it to plain text I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to encode your doc's id in the Document Term Matrix. You can do that by saving it as an attribute in your text corpus. Check out this [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24501981/6327771).