# Summarizing R corpus with doc ID

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

I've created a DocumentTermMatrix similar to the one in this post:

[Keep document ID with R corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501514/keep-document-id-with-r-corpus)

Where I've maintained the doc_id so I can join the data back to a larger data set.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to summarize the words and word count and keep the doc_id. I'd like to be able to join this data to an existing data set using only 3 columns (doc_id, word, freq).

Without needing the doc_id, this is straight forward and I use this code to get my end result.

```
df_source=DataframeSource(df)
df_corpus=VCorpus(df_source)
tdm=TermDocumentMatrix(df_corpus) 
tdm_m=as.matrix(tdm)

word_freqs=sort(rowSums(tdm_m), decreasing = TRUE)
tdm_sorted=data.frame(word = names(word_freqs), freq = word_freqs)
```

I've tried several different approaches to this and just cannot get it to work. This is where I am now ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPxYp.png)). I've used this code:

```
tdm_m=cbind("doc.id" =rownames(tdm_m),tdm_m)
```

to move the doc_id into a column in the matrix, but cannot get the numeric columns to sum and keep the doc_id associated.

Any help, greatly appreciated, thanks!

Expected result:

doc.id    |    word      |   frequency
1         |     Apple    |        2
2         |     Apple    |        1
3         |     Banana   |        4
3         |     Orange   |        1
4         |     Pear     |       3

Comment: Please add a small expected output to question.

Comment: Updated original question with expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at your expected output, you don't need to use this line of code `word_freqs=sort(rowSums(tdm_m), decreasing = TRUE)`. Because this creates a total sum of the word, like Apple = 3  instead of 2 and 1 over multiple documents.

To get to the output you want, instead of using `TermDocumentMatrix`, using `DocumentTermMatrix` is slightly easier. No need in switching columns around. I'm showing you two examples on how to get the result. One with `melt` from the reshape2 package and one with the `tidy` function from the tidytext package.

```
# example 1
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(df_corpus)
dtm_df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(dtm))
# remove 0 values and order the data.frame
dtm_df <- dtm_df[dtm_df$value > 0, ]
dtm_df <- dtm_df[order(dtm_df$value, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

or using `tidytext::tidy` to get the data into a tidy format. No need to remove the 0 values as tidytext doesn't transform it into a matrix before casting it into a data.frame

```
# example 2
dtm_tidy <- tidytext::tidy(dtm)
# order the data.frame or start using dplyr syntax if needed
dtm_tidy <- dtm_tidy[order(dtm_tidy$count, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

In my tests tidytext is a lot faster and uses less memory as there is no need to first create a dense matrix.